# Jquery help, on(click

Tags: jquery, html, click

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="partners-container">
    <div class="clickme">
        <div class="partners-bars">
            Huvudpartners & Sponsorer
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="showornot hidden">
        <div class="partners-post-wrapper">
            <div class="partners-post">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ThMn1MQ.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the jquery right now for toggling the post:

```
$('.clickme').on('click', function(){
    $('.network-container .showornot').slideToggle(400);
});
```

Unfortunately I got many more "categorys with the same class =partners-container and .clickme so what this code does is that it toggles the first one:
http://gyazo.com/c2dc7a1ae531124ac43d57d03b1dcb5c

But I want the rest to be be able to get toggled aswell, and rest closed. Anyone that could help me? I know I should use "this" but i'm not sure how to do that.

.showornot should be toggled when clicking on its parents child clickme... I know it's messy haha

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the shorthand method .click?

http://api.jquery.com/click/

Then, try the following:

```
$(".showornot", $(this).parent()).slideToggle(400);
```

Working proof:
http://jsfiddle.net/dg2z67hx/3/

What I am doing in this fiddle is selecting the element with the class .showornot INSIDE the button's parent element.

Please note that **you are missing a starting div tag from the code you posted**, I presume it's the one classed as 'network-container', that makes it a little harder for people to answer.

Comment: Hi thankyou for your reply, unfortunately it does the same thing as the last example I showed you. It still toggles the first post, but the other ones doesn't toggle.

Comment: I forgot to tell you, every post got it's own <div class="partners-container">

Comment: Did you look at my fiddle? It was working there and each element was inside it's own partners-container div.

Comment: Your fiddle didn't even refer to jquery... Here's a working version http://jsfiddle.net/okztzm54/3/